# Can I make an Android app that runs a web view in Chrome 39?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm developing an Android app that's a web page embedded inside of a web view. The web page makes use of the web audio API. It looks like Chrome 39 for Android supports that API, but no version of the basic Android browser does: http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio%20api

Can I detect support for Chrome 39 on an Android device? And open the web page using Chrome 39?

And ask the user to download it if he/she does not have it?

Comment: No, as of now you can not run apps in Chrome instance. You will have to ship Chrome bundled with your app.

Comment: With the release of Android 5.0 (Lollipop), the WebView framework will be updated from the Google Play store.  It will probably be updated fairly regularly as Chrome releases occur.

[WebView changes in Lollipop](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#WebView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) to query if chrome (com.android.chrome) is installed and then retrieve the version info.

```
try {
    // Get installed Chrome package info
    String chromePackageName = "com.android.chrome";
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(chromePackageName, 0);

    // Check the version number
    int versionMajor = Integer.parseInt(info.versionName.subString(0, 2));
    if(versionMajor < 39) {
        // Chrome is installed but not updated, prompt user to update it
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + chromePackageName)));
    } else {
        // Chrome is installed and at or above version 39, launch the page
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://YourURLHere")));
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Chrome isn't installed, prompt the user to download it.
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + chromePackageName)));

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Something funky happened since the first two chars aren't a number
}
```

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with a _`WebView`_.

Comment: Ah, good point. Any idea how I could open a web view using Chrome 39? Assuming that it's been installed?

Comment: WebViews prior to Lollipop are not updatable and [run at Chromium versions 30, 33, and 36](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_version_of_chrome_is_it_based_on_).  You will not be able to change the versions of Chromium that the WebView uses by [updating Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_this_mean_chrome_for_android_is_using_the_webview_). Only devices >= Android 5.0 will have up-to-date versions of Chromium that the WebView will use.