# can't not support for chrome 39 api 19 version

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio, video

I use webview from extends from WebViewClient ...show for audio video from chrome support for android api18 and under only but can't not support my audio video file for chrome version 30 and above.how i can solve for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not force the WebView API to use an updated version of Chrome.  Prior to Android 5.0, the WebView framework was fixed at specific Chrome releases <= 36 (see this official [FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_version_of_chrome_is_it_based_on_)

With the release of Android 5.0 (Lollipop), the WebView component is updated via the Google Play store and will have updates similar to chromium releases.

[WebView updates in Lollipop](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#WebView)

You can detect whether the user has chrome >= 39 installed and launch your page through chrome if you wish ([see related post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873566/can-i-make-an-android-app-that-runs-a-web-view-in-chrome-39/28012329#28012329))